# Java inner class import to Scala project

Tags: java, scala

I want to import java inner class into Scala project. The code, which wouldn't compile looks like this:

```
import pac.Obj
import pac.Obj.Inner.Inner2

object Sample {
    def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {            
        var o = new Obj()
        Inner2 i2 = o.getInner().addInner2("some text")
    }
}
```

The scala compiler is unable to recognize the second import. Why is that? In Java, this construct works fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Inner2 i2` is illegal in Scala in any case, and `val i2 = o.getInner().addInner2("some text")` will work fine.

Answer (score 10):

It does work if the `Inner` class is `static`.

If it isn't, well you're out of luck (but do you really need it?). But you can use the name with the `#` separator like this:

```
var inner = outer.getInner : Outer#Inner
```

Answer (score 1):

According to Iulian Dragos, who [would know](http://typesafe.com/company/team),

> There is indeed no syntax to import Outer#Inner.

([link](http://www.iulidragos.org/?p=166#comment-35))